# WPF Effects - on text

Tags: wpf, wpf-4.0

I've seen a variety of references to WPF effects, but it seems like they're for bitmaps, not text.  Is it possible to apply effects other than **Blur** or **Drop Shadow** to a **TextBlock** object in XAML?

Examples of what I'm wanting to do would be maybe an outline stroke, or a bevel/emboss effect.

Is there something you can do in XAML to convert a TextBlock into a bitmap and then apply bitmap effects to it?

A library would be fine, but so is coding it myself, but I don't even know where to start.  Is it possible? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Can you post what you want to do and what you've tried to accomplish it?stackoverflow doesn't allow questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. These kind of questions usually get flagged but if you edit your question you could avoid that and get some answers

Comment: I don't necessarily have a specific effect in mind, but something like adding an outline stroke to text would be an example. Or applying a bevel/emboss effect.    I have been searching online and not finding much info.

Comment: I would suggest you edit your question to include that information and remove the part asking for libraries.

Comment: I hadn't really thought I'd asked for a library... I was just trying to establish if this sort of thing even existed.

Comment: [Here is an example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748273%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, Frank, but I have Blur and DropShadow pretty well figured out.

Answer (score 3):

I think you basically have two options here, and which one you use really depends on which specific effects you are trying to implement. You may even want both.

### A Custom Element

As Frank J mentioned in his answer, the `FormattedText` class has a lot of power and allows you do to a lot of things. You can see several examples on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098.aspx).

You can build a custom element that extends a base class such as `FrameworkElement` and override the `OnRender` method to render your text using the `DrawText` method on the drawing context. You will want some method by which to specify and customize the effects you want to use for each instance of the control. I can think of two ways to do that:

1. Add dependency properties to the control for each thing that can be customized, and determine what to render in `OnRender` based on those properties.
2. Or, add a dependency property to the control to allow you to specify the effect to use. It would be typed as an effect base class or interface that you create with an appropriate API for using the effect. You could then create derived classes for each type of effect you want to implement. This would be similar to the pattern WPF uses with the `Effect` property, but using your own effect system.

Note: Make sure that any dependency properties you define which have an effect on rendering set the [AffectsRender](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkpropertymetadata.affectsrender.aspx) flag in their meta data when you create them.

### Shader Effects

Another option is to make use of the existing effect system WPF provides and write your own shader effects. It takes a bit of learning to setup a process for creating effects this way, but once you do it is relatively easy to add new effects.

**Warning:** Applying effects to elements may cause them to have very poor rendering performance if you render them without hardware acceleration (such as when rendering to a RenderTargetBitmap). You won't notice it if you use them sparingly, but get too many of them on the screen and your application can slow to a crawl. Use with care.

Here are steps you can take to get started with shader effects.

1. If you are not already familiar, learn about [HLSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb509561.aspx) (at least the basics). It is the language used to write WPF (and DirectX) compatible shaders. You only need to worry about pixel shaders for WPF, not vertex or geometry shaders.
2. Install some version of the Windows SDK if you don't have one. It includes the HLSL shader compiler command line program: [FXC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb232919.aspx). You will need it to compile your shaders before you can use them in WPF. You can run it manually, or simplify the process by configuring build steps in Visual Studio to run it for you in a given project.
3. Once you have shaders that are compiled, you will want to add them as resources to your WPF library or application that will be defining them.
4. Finally, create and implement a class that extends [ShaderEffect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.effects.shadereffect.aspx) and set it up to work with your shader. An instance of this class can be assigned to the `Effect` property on any element, similar to the built-in effects that come with WPF.

If you want a more complete guide on shader effects, do a web search for <kbd>WPF shader effects</kbd> and you will find a few out there.

**Existing Shader Effects**

There are third-party shader effects that you can use if you don't need something completely custom. There are even some [effects created by Microsoft](http://wpffx.codeplex.com/) that are offered as a standalone download.

Answer (score 2):

Look into the [Typography in WPF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742190%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article for more advanced effects using [`FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext(v=vs.110).aspx).

And here is the MSDN help for [drawing `FormattedText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752098(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I appreciate the effort, Frank, but my question was about adding effects _other_ than DropShadow and Blur to a TextBlock.

Comment: Updated my answer to remove the irrelevant parts that you have already figured out. The rest covers stuff like outlines and brushes.

Comment: The FormattedText class isn't something you can use directly in XAML. I figured if I had to end up writing code myself, I'd make a new **UIELement** subclass that used **FormattedText** to get things done, but I was hoping that there were a few existing XAML tricks out there I'd not found yet.

Comment: If you decide to go with a custom control, extend `FrameworkElement` rather than `UIElement` to get a lot of useful layout features for free like margins and alignments.

Comment: Frank, I have to apologize... I think I accidentally down voted your question when I was using my tablet.  I didn't intend to.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Xaviers answer is very comprehensive and illustrates in greater detail your options.  I did +1 his.